# ModX Revo: form action not working?

Tags: html, forms, content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution

I have a form on a ModX Revo resource that looks fine and is nothing special:

```
<form id="contactform" action="http://mysite.com/index.php?id=41" method="send">
<tr>
<td class="orange">Name*</td>
<td><input size="24" type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
</tr>
etc...
<tr>
<td id="tablecenter" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Send"></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

But when I hit send I just get redirected to the home page (404). The receiving resource (resource 41) is published and can be accessed fine in other ways, just not with this form action.

Tried both Send and Get methods as well as short and absolute URLs, but no difference.

Would anyone know why this would be occurring? Thanks!

(ps: FURLs are turned off on this site if it matters).

UPDATE: Seems to not just be resource 41 thats an issue - doesnt work with any resource

Comment: Also what you can do is instead of: action="http://mysite.com/index.php?id=41", use: action="[[~[[41]]]]" assuming of course you are posting to a modx resource :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Used method="post" instead. Seems to work ok. Closing question